# Seeking up-to-date shapefile for Pakistan

Tags: shapefile, data, pakistan

I'm currently looking for a shapefile for Pakistan with the current district borders. So far I found something on https://gadm.org/. Unfortunately the shapefile there seems not to be up-to-date, as e.g. one district has been split into two in 1996, but in the shapefile it's still one district (and in some other cases the names seem to be the old ones).

Is there any "general source" with newer shapefiles (also for other countries)?

Answer (score 1):

You can select your country and download shapefiles here:

http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata

Answer (score 0):

For official boundaries you should go to the Humanitarian Data Exchange (data.humdata.org). There you will find the shapefiles that the governments themselves submit to UN OCHA for humanitarian purposes, so it should be the validated one. Note that these boundaries might differ from the boundaries presented by other countries, or by those agreed upon by the UN, since territorial disputes can be at play.